# Populating select options with for loop

Tags: html, scala, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I would like to populate select options with a for loop in Play Framework / Scala.
In order to do that my in template ,i am doing this;

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-size="auto" data-live-search="true" data-container="body" >
@for(provider <- providerlist){
<option value="@provider.providerId.toString()">@provider.providerName.toString()</option>
}
</select>
```

However, my problem is,  with this implementation i cannot see all the options instead i have just seen the first one yet.
This is my input :

```
@(providerlist:java.util.ArrayList[model.Provider])
```

I am using Play framework with scala and twitter-bootstrap and bootstrap-select.js

Comment: Whenever i delete the class , it works then. there must be a problem with bootstrap-select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bootstrap-select.js problem , when i delete the class option of the select , problem has been solved.